# Failed to print get count result in forloop

Tags: scala

I have been trying to count inside a for loop, but the result just ends with a parentheses. I am just printing out the key here in map.

```
var count = 0
xs.foreach(x => (myMap += ((count+=1).toString+","+java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString -> x)))
```

Output:

```
(),901e9926-be1e-4dc4-b3e3-6c3b2feea2c4
```

Expected output:

```
1,901e9926-be1e-4dc4-b3e3-6c3b2feea2c4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `foreach`, `count += 1` would be of type `Unit`.  If I understand your question correctly, the example below (using an arbitrary `xs` collection) might be what you're looking for:

```
val xs = List("a", "b", "c", "d")

var count = 0
var myMap = Map[String, String]()

xs.foreach{ x =>
  count += 1
  myMap += ((count.toString + "," + java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString) -> x)
}

myMap.keys
// res1: Iterable[String] = Set(
//   1,bd971c44-b9d0-41a0-b59f-3acbf2e0dee0, 2,5459eed9-309d-4f9c-afd7-10aced9df2a0,
//   3,5816ea42-d8ed-4beb-8b30-0376d0674700, 4,30f6f22f-1e6d-4eec-86af-5bc6734d5196
// )
```

In case you want a more idiomatic approach, using `zip` for the count and `foldLeft` for Map aggregation would produce similar result:

```
val myMap = Map[String, String]()

val resultMap = xs.zip(Stream from 1).foldLeft( myMap )(
  (m, x) => m + ((x._2.toString + "," + java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString) -> x._1)
)
```

Comment: @Thank you! i didn't know going to the next line after after count += 1 would stop erroring in Intelli J

Answer (score 1):

What you are printing here is actually `(count+=1).toString`. In Scala, an assignment like this will be evaluated to `Unit`, which is expressed by parentheses. That's why you print `()` and not the value of `count`. If you check the `count` variable value afterwards you will see that it is `1` as expected.

---

Additionally, what you are trying to do could be expressed in a better way, e.g, you could do:

```
val myMap = xs.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2 + 1) + "," + java.util.UUID.randomUUID -> x._1).toMap
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and concide way. the (X._2 + 1) just appends index with 1. Doesn't actually add

Comment: @dedpo: Are you sure you ran it correctly? `x._2` is just an int so it should be added together and not appended. I tried it out and got the correct results.